# Auto Layout in rendered view doesn't update its frames

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view created from a xib with various labels on it. I don't add this view to my screen, instead I render it in context to create a UIImage out of it which the user can then export.

The view uses auto layout to reposition the labels based on their content. When I add this view to a superview and display it on the screen everything is positioned correctly, but if I just render it in context then none of the auto-layout constraints are applied; all the label's sizes are exactly where they are in the original xib.

How do I make the view apply its constraints?

I've tried the following without success:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
[view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[view setNeedsLayout];
[view setNeedsDisplay];
[view layoutSubviews];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `layoutIfNeeded`

```
[yourView layoutIfNeeded];
```

This will provide you updated frame. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is for releasing/grabbing  the hold of constraints. You can use this as per need.